# While pulling data from database with php

Tags: php

I keep getting
Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in xx on line 6

error what is the problem with this code ? how can I fix it ?

```
$read = mysql_query("select * from detail");

while($wr = mysql_fetch_array($read)) {
echo $wr['Who'];
echo "<br />";
echo $wr['Time'];
echo "<br />";
echo $wr['What'];
}
```

edit; I made it like this still giving an error.

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'panel');
$sql = "select * from detail";
$read = $db->query($sql);

while($wr = mysql_fetch_array($read)) {
echo $wr['Who'];
echo "<br />";
echo $wr['Time'];
echo "<br />";
echo $wr['What'];
}
```

Comment: If you search for the exact error message, you get more than enough similar questions. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/php-error-mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given

Comment: I did. everybody have different solutions to each problem. Mine must be so easy

Comment: What does `var_dump($read)` give you right before the loop?

Comment: object(mysqli_result)[2]
  public 'current_field' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'lengths' => null
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'type' => null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing the MySQL and MySQLi extensions!
Use the [appropriate functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) of either, not both.

Comment: Thanks for the clue I just added "i" to mysql now problem solved. I put while($wr = mysqli_fetch_array($read)) { instead of while($wr = mysql_fetch_array($read)) {

Answer (score 1):

You probably having problems with querying database since your query fails:

```
$read = mysql_query("select * from detail"); // $read is false

// You can try to discover the error.
$read = mysql_query("select * from detail") || die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: `mysql_query` should return `resource`, but it's returning `FALSE` and this means there is an error

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$read = mysql_query("select * from detail");

while($wr = mysql_fetch_array($read,  MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo $wr['Who'];
echo "<br />";
echo $wr['Time'];
echo "<br />";
echo $wr['What'];
}
```

See for more information: [mysql-fetch-array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: Why not `mysql_fetch_assoc`? And this isn't answer to question.